# Angularjs remote reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function to change a scope object in an angularjs app:

```
function change() {
    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="appController"]');
    var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.globalUrl = 'http://google.com/';
    });
}
```

this is working for the browser calling the function. Is it possible to change this scope for every Browser currently viewing the app (someone clicks a button and everyone gets a notice)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with a async server. If you use Node.js, you can try Socket.io or Meteor.js, or Python with Tornado. This type of application like chats, googledocs and others use this arch.
You can try integrate it with a angular service.
http://socket.io/demos/chat/

Answer (score 0):

> someone clicks a button and everyone gets a notice

For that you would need some server side interaction, not just AngularJS code.